# How to remove only year from a reference?

Tags: bibtex

While I am citing references, I have some reference (web addresses) that I need to refer. They dont have year of publication. So, when I give year={} in bibtex, it is displaying () in the place of reference in thesis. How to remove this ()??

Comment: Could we have a minimal example?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you using `natbib`?

Answer (score 1):

You can cite webpages with a code you can see below:

```
@online{WebPage,
author       = {StackExchange},
howpublished = "<URL: \url{://tex.stackexchange.com/}>. Cited 5.7.2015"
}
```

It is always a good thing to mention what is the date you have cited the webpage.

Comment: That would require a style that supports the `@online` type. AFAIK most `bibtex` styles do not.

Comment: At least unsrt supports @online type, and that is the style I have used. Before I have used also some other types also successfully.